# Access another view's content from another view

Tags: android

I have an activity with two view.One view has the buttons and the other is main view.I must disable buttons for some circumstances inside main view.I couldn't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

```
Button myBtn = (Button) ((MyActivity)getContext()).findViewById(R.id.mybtn);
```

I was calling this code inside constructor of my view.

That's why it's not working.
Now it's working...

Comment: Hey I'm trying to do same thing as yours but I can't use get Context like this. (Eclipse underlines in red) How did you use this? Can you post sample?